# Google Contacts OAUTH2

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to fetch Google Contacts but when user login option appears on it shows asks permission for `Know your age range and language`. But no permissions for contacts. Also when user is logged in successfully it redirects me to google search page.

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
var peopleDataArray: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = ""

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

}
fileprivate func performGetRequest(targetURL: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: NSError?) -> Void){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error as NSError?)
        })        }
    task.resume()
}


func getPeopleList() {
    let urlString = ("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?access_token=\(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.accessToken)")
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URLRequest)!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error")
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                                // Get the array with people data dictionaries.

                print(json)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                })

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()

}

}

    extension ViewController: GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate{


        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
            if let err = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                getPeopleList()
            }
        }


    }
```

URL Scheme

[image]

Comment: the tasks seems pretty simple as u haven't added scope to request the people

Comment: @ManuGupta Where ?

Comment: Check 'getPeopleList'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = ""

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly")


GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

}
```

You need to add these scopes and then try as know you are only asking permission to get your information

```
 // App Delegate Handle Url Scheme
 open func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
 sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    var returnScheme: Bool!
    if url.scheme == "dropbox"{
        returnScheme = true
    }else if url.scheme == "Goolge URL SCHEME Which you have added in plist file"{
        returnScheme = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                         sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                         annotation: annotation)
    }
    return returnScheme
}
```

Comment: This helped me show Contacts permission but after login it goes to google search page. That issue still arises.

Comment: have u implemented the url scheme in your application to redirect you back to the application. if url.scheme == ""{
            returnScheme = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                             annotation: annotation)
        }

Comment: Yes. App would crash if I miss adding url schemes.

Comment: @ nitesh can u post the code for url scheme you have implemented this is the only issue possible

Comment: Please check main post, updated PIC. I have not done it via code.

Comment: you have handle this in your app delegate class i am posting an example by editing my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142522/discussion-between-manu-gupta-and-nitesh).